# Browser add-on that automatically takes screenshot when I visit a certain page and saves it locally

Tags: web-browser, screenshot

Is there a browser add-on that automatically takes a screenshot when I visit a certain page and saves it to `<site>/<timestamp>.png`?

It could be for Firefox or Chrome, doesn't matter.

Comment: The OS *might* also be needed if it is a program that runs in the background and somehow detects the site...?

Comment: No, it should add `document.onload` or `window.onload` handler

Comment: @basin I was mainly saying it for the part where the screenshot is actually saved. AFAIK, there isn't an easy (if any!) way to save a file to a predefined path automatically, without a dialog in JavaScript, so the likelihood of a client program needed to be installed is quite high. But, I'm no FF/Chrome extension guru, so I may be wrong! :)

Comment: There're a few screenshot addons, but they require user interaction. There're some that inject JS to page, but none I know allow custom privileged action on JS events